# Does "dining" refer only to "dinner"?

Tags: grammaticality, american-english

Does *dining* refer only to *dinner*? What should I say when I am not joining a team/group for lunch? Is the following grammatical?

> Sorry I'm not dining with you for the lunch.

Is "for the lunch" necessary to mention?

Or can I omit the word *dining* and use *joining* instead?

> Sorry I'm not joining with you for the lunch.

Comment: Please support our proposed sister site for [English language learners](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/41665/english-language-learners?referrer=NIy3I1OlXZ2EgMrV1X1RuQ2). Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

*Dining* does not only refer to dinner: a hotel will usually serve lunch in the *dining room*, for example. But if you say you plan to *dine out*, most people will take that to mean go out for an evening meal.

But except in set phrases like *dine out*, *dine out on*, *dining room*, *dine with the devil*, *he wined and dined her*, it is a very formal word, and you would not use it in an informal conversation about joining someone for lunch, and if you say *come and dine with me* to invite someone to dinner, you will sound as though you have been reading too many historical novels.

And... not *join with you for the lunch*, just *join you for lunch*.

Answer (score 0):

Using "joining" is perfectly fine. "I won't be joining you for lunch" sounds great to me.